# Uninstalling Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-xp, uninstall

How I can uninstall Ubuntu? I have Windows XP and I have watched many tutorials on EasyBCD but it's for Vista or Windows 7. The rest of the tutorials said that I need my Windows XP disk to recover the master boot but I don't have that.

Is there any way to uninstall it, or is there another program to repair my master boot?

Comment: If you have installed Ubuntu on a separate partition, there is no uninstall. You can wipe the partition at the most.
Are you able to boot into windows now (with ubuntu still installed on the other partition)? Grub2, the boot loader should have added an entry for windows

Answer (score 0):

I've done it by myself. I removed ubuntu partition then put the ubuntu CD and and boot my PC from there. So now I've reinstalled (not uninstalled) ubuntu and everything work perfectly.

**Edited for** *Simon Sheehan* :
I've inserted the Ubuntu CD for installing ubuntu (I've downloaded the ubuntu from their official site and bur it to CD). Then if the computer doesn't boot your CD u have to enter the BIOS and set the booting order - put CD-ROM on first place. Then restart and your computer should boot ubuntu installing.
When on windows click right mouse button and enter manage->disk management then find the ubuntu partition (usually this is a partition about 10GB (the size that you have allocated in the beginning ) ans with no letter (like C,D)) then right click and delete. Then If you want to use that partition on windows right click and click Make new logical drive (I'm not sure because now I'm not using Windows). Hope the you received your answers.

Comment: "Boot my PC from there" from where? What on the CD let's you boot to this? How did you remove the partition? If you could, please edit your answer to include more details

Answer (score 0):

I would try using BOOTICE on XP. You can use it to install the Windows XP boot sector in a rather simple matter.

Simply select the Hard Disk XP boots from, usually the one XP is installed on. Then, select `Process MBR`, and choose the one for XP. I believe on some versions, this bootloader will be referred to as `ntldr`, whereas others will refer to it as `Windows XP 5.x MBR`. Either way, that's the one you want to select. Click `Install/Config` at the bottom, click OK in the box that appears next, and you're done!

Also, if for some reason you can't boot from XP, there's a CD image called Hiren's Boot CD, which is based off Windows XP, which has this program pre-installed. Simpy burn this CD, boot from it, and use the menu in the Tray area (the lower-left corner of your screen), and you'll find it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the Windows  repair disk. It's a 100MB ISO which should've either come with your system, or can you can google for it. Burn it onto a flash drive with Universal USB Installer to make it bootable, and restart.
2. Enter the Windows repair mode (i.e boot from above pendrive), go to Repair Computer->Administrator Prompt, and enter $ bootrec.exe /fixmbr
3. Restart and you'll have your Windows MBR restored. Note that if you have any other linux partitions those MBR entries will be gone and you'll have to install GRUB2 again. If you have only Windows then it's fixed.